# How do I edit the Login page in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to edit the Register / Login page of my Magento 1.8 site. But I not exactly sure what folder path or folder I need to get to in order to edit the correct file.

I knew how to do it awhile ago when I customized my website, but it has been quite some time and I have forgotten how to get to the location.

Can someone please let me know what what folder path I need to follow in order to find the Register / Login page so I can do some quick edits.

Thanks, any helps is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to locate a `phtml` file it's best to turn on template hints.

1. Disable cache
2. In the backend go to `System` > `Configuration` > `Developer` and fill out your IP
3. Change the scope to website level with the top left dropdown
4. Turn on `Template Path Hints` under `Debug`

In the frontend refresh the page and the path to the login template should be visible.

There's actually two places to look for login file. Older versions stored it in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/login.phtml` and newer ones use persistent catalog `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`